# My NVIDIA GEFORCE 610 in Asus A43SD doesn't recognize on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia

I was trying to install VGA card because it doesn't recognize on "Additional Driver" so I try to install it manually with following these steps :

Download Driver from [www.nvidia.org](http://www.nvidia.org)
Adjust the type you have NVIDIA. The results are usually berekstension driver. Run
Copy of Driver is in your home folder, then open terminal and type

`sudo gedit / etc / modprobe.d / blacklist.conf`

Then add the sequence at the end blacklist.conf:
blacklist nouveau
then save.
Then go to the Command line mode, by pressing ctrl + alt + f1, then do login

Once the login is successful, then typing:

`sudo stop lightdm` (to temporarily turn off xserver)

`sudo apt-get - purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` (Pruging Nouveau)

`sudo update-initramfs-u` (then restart)

Steps 2-4 serves nouveau remove kernel that contains the default driver of ubuntu, to install the Nvidia driver.

Then login as normal (mode DE (Desktop Environment / GUI)), re-press the ctrl + alt + f1 and log in command line, turn off Xserver such as step 4.

then install the Nvidia driver.

Installation steps in a way, find the directory where the downloaded nvidia drivers are. Then typing in the command line:

`sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.59.run` (adjust the driver file name)

Window will then appear on the command line to install and configure the Nvidia Driver.

but at least, my screen become small
for early resolution of 1366 x 768 to 640 x 480 VGA card and still not read the "Additional Drivers"

If my VGA Card can't read on "Additional Driver", I can't to access Compiz Manager

hope you can help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop is nvidia optimus enabled laptop. The only way to use this card fully if there is an option in BIOS to disable integrated intel card.

In optimus technology the nvidia card isn't connected to the laptop display. The frames generated by nvidia is transported through intel card. As nvidia doesn't provide support for optimus in their linux driver. You can't use the nvidia card in linux with full capability. And the graphics card detected by ubuntu will be always Intel card.

In nvidia driver download page, if you see the information. It is clearly written

> Some designs incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA
> Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs
> with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to
> disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available.

So first thing to is uninstall the driver you have installed. Do the followings once you are in tty1 mode

`sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.59.run --uninstall`

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Reboot using `sudo reboot now`

Now your laptop in this state (same state like after a fresh installation) it has two problems.

1. Both graphics card is on, leading to high temperature and battery consumption
2. You can't use nvidia card at all.

To solve this problem and use nvidia card to some extent (not fully) the solution is to install Bumblebee.

**Instruction for installing [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org) to turn off  discrete  GPU and enable only when required**

1. Type the following in terminal,

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
   then
   `sudo apt-get update`
2. To install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

   `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`
3. Reboot.

---

**Usage Instruction :**

To run a program with nvidia card, use `optirun` command prefixed in terminal.
Like to run `glxspheres` with nvidia card type

`optirun glxspheres`

To run firefox type : `optirun firefox &`

---

To get the graphics card model detected by ubuntu, install [mesa-utils](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mesa-utils) [image: Install mesa-utils].**Again Remember the graphics card model won't be nvidia one. It will be intel, because in nvidia optimus the nvidia card isn't exposed directly. Nvidia card is wired via the intel one**